# Find overlap time ranges

Tags: python

I am having the following data which is sorted by start time in ascendong order:

```
---------------------------
Name | start | end  | count|
A    | 3:00  | 4:00 | 6    |
B    | 3:00  | 4:00 | 6    |
C    | 3:00  | 4:00 | 6    |
D    | 3:00  | 3:30 | 6    |
E    | 3:32  | 4:00 | 6    |
F    | 4:01  | 5:00 | 6    |
----------------------------
```

I am using below logic to find the overlap:

```
max(start1,start2) < min(end1,end2)
```

I need to generate the below output. Basically find all the overlap and non-overlap data

```
Expected Output
(A,B,C,D) - 24 - Overlap - Here E is not included since E is started by the time D is finished
(A,B,C,E) - 24 - overlap - D is excluded since its already over
(F) - 6 - No overlap
```

Comment: Which framework? Pandas?

Comment: No framework as such.

Comment: That is all a string? That's rather inefficient.

Comment: What would be the expected output if there were a row `G | 3:20 | 3:40 | 5`?

Comment: Not actually. I have data in seconds. But for representing I convert here into actual time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, if you represent your data by a graph with a vertex for every row, and an edge between two rows if their time slots overlap, then what you are looking for is the set of [maximal cliques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)) in that graph. With your input data, and using [`networkx.find_cliques`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.clique.find_cliques.html) to find the cliques:

```py
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])
G.add_edges_from([['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['A', 'D'], ['A', 'E'], ['B', 'C'], ['B', 'D'], ['B', 'E'], ['C', 'D'], ['C', 'E']])

print(list(nx.find_cliques(G)))
# Output: [['A', 'C', 'B', 'E'], ['A', 'C', 'B', 'D'], ['F']]
```

You mention in your comments that you actually have your data in seconds, so let me assume that what you provide as an input are the times as integers. Then you can make use of the above approach as follows:

```py
def overlap(df):
    G = nx.Graph()
    G.add_nodes_from(df.Name)
    for i in range(len(df)):
        a = df.iloc[i]
        for j in range(i + 1, len(df)):
            b = df.iloc[j]
            if (a.start <= b.start and a.end >= b.start) or (b.start <= a.start and b.end >= a.start):
                G.add_edge(a.Name, b.Name)
    for clique in nx.find_cliques(G):
        yield clique, df.set_index('Name').loc[clique]['count'].sum()
```

With your example:

```py
In [53]: df
Out[53]:
  Name  start  end  count
0    A    180  240      6
1    B    180  240      6
2    C    180  240      6
3    D    180  210      6
4    E    212  240      6
5    F    241  300      6

In [54]: list(overlap(df))
Out[54]: [(['F'], 6), (['B', 'C', 'A', 'D'], 24), (['B', 'C', 'A', 'E'], 24)]
```

Or perhaps, what you are interested in are the possible overlaps at any given time (which is not the same as the above). By noting that the only times which it is relevant to consider are those that appear as start or end times, those are easy enough to find as well:

```py
In [69]: set(tuple(df[(df.start <= t) & (df.end >= t)].Name) for t in set(df.start).union(df.end))
Out[69]: {('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), ('A', 'B', 'C', 'E'), ('F',)}
```

This can be used the same way as the clique finding method:

```py
def overlap2(df):
    for overlap in set(tuple(df[(df.start <= t) & (df.end >= t)].Name) for t in set(df.start).union(df.end)):
        yield overlap, df.set_index('Name').loc[list(overlap)]['count'].sum()
```

For example:

```py
In [88]: list(overlap2(df))
Out[88]: [(('F',), 6), (('A', 'B', 'C', 'E'), 24), (('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), 24)]
```

As an example where this makes a difference, consider what happens when a row is added with a start of 200 and an end of 220:

```py
In [90]: df
Out[90]:
  Name  start  end  count
0    A    180  240      6
1    B    180  240      6
2    C    180  240      6
3    D    180  210      6
4    E    212  240      6
5    F    241  300      6
6    G    200  220      3

In [94]: list(overlap(df))
Out[94]: [(['F'], 6), (['G', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'D'], 27), (['G', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'E'], 27)]

In [95]: list(overlap2(df))
Out[95]:
[(('A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'G'), 27),
 (('F',), 6),
 (('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'G'), 27),
 (('A', 'B', 'C', 'E'), 24),
 (('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), 24)]
```

Comment: if we add G, then there is an overlap between D and G correct?

Comment: Yep, that was the idea.

Comment: what is the difference between overlap and overlap2?

Comment: `overlap2` gives possible concurrent rows at all possible times; `overlap` doesn't. From the wording in the original post, it's not clear which one is expected (and as you can see, they both give the same result on the given example).

Comment: thank you for providing a solution. I am currently using the overlap function. One thing I noticed is that when we have large amount of data 'find_cliques' method is taking lot of time to return the result set. is there anyway, we can optimize this solution?

Comment: NetworkX tends to not focus much on performance; it's open source so you can have a look at [the source](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/algorithms/clique.html#find_cliques) to see if your problem has structure that allows you to optimize away part of the implementation. In any case, the maximum clique problem is well-studied, so you might be able to dig up more performant implementations elsewhere. A quick search suggests that SageMath has a Cython implementation that might be useful.

Comment: Also, you're sure that it's `find_cliques` and not the pandas initialization code that's slow, right? In general, looping over the rows of a data frame is bad if you like performance, and simply passing to the `.values` of the data frame tends to give a large speed-up.

Comment: A quick check showed nested for loops(O(n)2) is taking time to draw the edges between nodes.